# How to represent a common Object type in Flow?

Tags: flowtype

`var obj: Object;`
seems to work, but I couldn't find this syntax in docs. Or should I see it as a class type for Object?

PS: by common Object type, I mean a value of this type should satisfy:

```
value && typeof value === 'object'
```

Comment: Define "common object". You haven't given any examples of the data that you want to match, so I don't see a way to give you useful feedback.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I've defined it in my edit.

Comment: @ftor that's not the case. `{}` and `Object` are types which behave very differently. In particular, `Object` is an unsafe type -- Flow will allow you to access any property on it and do whatever you want with that property. In contrast, Flow will allow you access to no properties on `{}`.

Comment: @NatMote You are right. I removed my comment. I guess `Object` is a nominal type then.

Comment: It's not even a nominal type. It's just a catchall. You don't need to explicitly declare that some type is a subtype of `Object` for Flow to consider it a subtype. Classes in Flow have nominal subtyping rules, meaning that even if two classes have the same interface, their instances are not interchangeable. In contrast, ordinary object types have structural subtyping rules.

Comment: @NatMote OK, I think I understand what you say. What confused me is the fact that `Object` is a catchall except for the `[]` type, which is an object type as well in Javascript - with special internal properties though. Since `Object` is a catchall you don't need to declare subtype relationships explicitly as you would have to with a nominal type. Thanks!